# How to turn off the "Look up" function on the touchpad completely?

Tags: macos, look-up

When I click with two fingers to open a link in a new window, Safari too often turn on the "Look Up" function. It is annoying, and I have tried to turn it off in System Preferences > Touchpad > Point & Click to no avail. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. :) If possible, could you edit your question to include the version of macOS you're using? There's an _edit_ link below the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### macOS 10.12 Sierra

1. Open **System Preferences**
2. Click on **Trackpad > Point & Click**
3. Uncheck **Look up & data detectors**

Does this work for you?